# Deleting a node and its relationships in a graph database using Cypher

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I need to delete a node and all its relationships in a graph database using Cypher. Can you provide an example of how to do this, and is it possible to undo or roll back these changes if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a node and its relationships using Cypher, use the `DETACH DELETE` command. For example, to delete all Movie nodes where movie names start with the word "The" and all relationships for such nodes, we can write the query below:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE m.name STARTS WITH 'The'
DETACH DELETE m;
```

The `DELETE` command will delete the nodes and `DETACH` command will delete all relationships for the nodes.